# При нажатии на кнопку увеличивается не тот блок JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, this

Есть родительский блок, который при нажатии на кнопку создает такой же дочерний блок рядом. На блоках есть кнопка увеличение/уменьшение блока, которому принадлежит кнопка. Однако, если нажать на кнопку увеличения родительского блока после создания первого дочернего блока, то увеличивается первый дочерний блок. Как исправить эту ошибку?

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("zoomin")) {  
        var father = this;
        var card = father.getElementsByClassName("card")[0];
              card.style.height = card.offsetHeight + 50 + 'px';
              card.style.width = card.offsetWidth + 50 + 'px';
    }
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("lvl1blue")) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var father = e.path[5];
        var col = document.getElementsByClassName('col')[0];
            var content = col.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
                  content.appendChild(div);
        div.classList = father.classList;
        div.innerHTML = father.innerHTML
            div.classList.remove("col");

    }
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.fa,
.fas {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:focus{
  outline:0
}

article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f5f7fa;
}

html,
body {
  scrollbar-color: red #1a1a1a;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

body .card {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.in-kod + .in-kod {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

body .card .multi-button {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
}

body .card .multi-button button {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:hover {
  background: var(--text);
  color: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 15.625%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 66%;
  top: 15.625%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 15.625%;
  top: 50%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 62.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
  background: #743da0;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
  background: #3f72c3;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(4),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(4) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 62.5%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body .card .cardcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
}

body .card:hover .multi-button,
body .card .multi-button:focus-within {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px #f3faf7;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

.col {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  left: 0;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  left: 300px;
}

.col:nth-child(3) {  
  left: 600px;
}

.col:nth-child(4) {
  left: 900px;
}


.schema2 {
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  --background: #3f72c3;
  --text: white;
}

.purple {
  --background: #743da0;
  --text: white;
}

.white {
  --background: #e3e8e6;
  --text: black;
}

.arguments {
  z-index: 9999999999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2;
  border: none;
}

.arguments:focus{
  outline:0
}

.add {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

.btn,
.btn2 {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.in-kod {
  display: block;
}
<link rel='stylesheet' hre
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css'>

<div class="col">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col">
  <span class="in-kod">
    <div class="card blue">
      <div class="multi-button">
        <span class="add">
          <button class="btn2 lvl1blue">+</button>
          <button class="btn zoomin">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
        </div>
      <div class="cardcontainer"></div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое хотелм получить?

```js
function addBlueBox(e) {

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let father = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(father);
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName('col')[0];
        var content = col.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
              content.appendChild(div);
    div.classList = father.classList;
    div.innerHTML = father.innerHTML;
    
    let newBtns = div.getElementsByClassName('btn2');   
    let newZoomins = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomin');    
    [...newBtns].forEach(button=>button.addEventListener("click", addBlueBox));        
    [...newZoomins].forEach(button=>button.addEventListener("click", zoomIn));    
    
    div.classList.remove("col");
};

function zoomIn(e){
 let father = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  var card = father.getElementsByClassName("card")[0];
  card.style.height = card.offsetHeight + 50 + 'px';
  card.style.width = card.offsetWidth + 50 + 'px';
}


let btn2s = document.getElementsByClassName('btn2');
let zoomins = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomin');

[...btn2s].forEach(button=>button.addEventListener("click", addBlueBox));
[...zoomins].forEach(button=>button.addEventListener("click", zoomIn));
```

```css
html {
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.fa,
.fas {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:focus{
  outline:0
}

article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f5f7fa;
}

html,
body {
  scrollbar-color: red #1a1a1a;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

body .card {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.in-kod + .in-kod {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

body .card .multi-button {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
}

body .card .multi-button button {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:hover {
  background: var(--text);
  color: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 15.625%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 66%;
  top: 15.625%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 15.625%;
  top: 50%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 62.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
  background: #743da0;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
  background: #3f72c3;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(4),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(4) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 62.5%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body .card .cardcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
}

body .card:hover .multi-button,
body .card .multi-button:focus-within {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px #f3faf7;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

.col {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  left: 0;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  left: 300px;
}

.col:nth-child(3) {  
  left: 600px;
}

.col:nth-child(4) {
  left: 900px;
}


.schema2 {
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  --background: #3f72c3;
  --text: white;
}

.purple {
  --background: #743da0;
  --text: white;
}

.white {
  --background: #e3e8e6;
  --text: black;
}

.arguments {
  z-index: 9999999999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2;
  border: none;
}

.arguments:focus{
  outline:0
}

.add {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

.btn,
.btn2 {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.in-kod {
  display: block;
}
<link rel='stylesheet' hre
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css'>

<div class="col">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col">
  <span class="in-kod">
    <div class="card blue">
      <div class="multi-button">
        <span class="add">
          <button class="btn2 lvl1blue">+</button>
          <button class="btn zoomin">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
        </div>
      <div class="cardcontainer"></div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```